# Get a youtube ID based on URL API V3?

Tags: php, youtube

I am trying to get the youtube id based on any youtube URL. I generated a key. The thing is based on this id I want to retrieve the title and description like the following URL

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=MY_ID&key=MY_KEY&alt=json&prettyprint=true

right now I am using PHP to distill the video ID from a ULR and then pass it to the link above using this method that I found in stackoverflow

```
$url_string = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($url_string, $args);
return isset($args['v']) ? $args['v'] : false;
```

This method hasn't worked each time. I tried also a regular expression but I'm having the same problem. Also, I searched in https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/. Any suggestions!!

thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example URL where this method doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines will get the Title and Description of a YouTube movie based on a URL (set `$url` to the appropriate URL):

```
<?php

$url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SpNHMwwID4";
parse_str(parse_url($url)['query'], $args);

$googleAPI = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos";
$googleAPI .= "?part=snippet";
$googleAPI .= "&id=" . $args['v'];
$googleAPI .= "&key={YOUR-API-KEY}";

$JSON = file_get_contents($googleAPI);
$videoResponse = json_decode($JSON, true);

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Video information</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  Title: <?= $videoResponse['items'][0]['snippet']['title']; ?><br/>
  Description: <?= $videoResponse['items'][0]['snippet']['description']; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can do something similar with the YouTube PHP client library (again set `$url` appropriately):

```
<?php

require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setDeveloperKey('{YOUR-API-KEY}');
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

$url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SpNHMwwID4";
parse_str(parse_url($url)['query'], $args);

$videoResponse = $youtube->videos->listVideos('snippet', array(
    'id' => $args['v']
));

$title = $videoResponse['items'][0]['snippet']['title'];
$description = $videoResponse['items'][0]['snippet']['description'];
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Video information</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  Title: <?= $title ?><br/>
  Description: <?= $description ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this methodology won't work for https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RgKAFK5djSk&list=PLc6GzkmQ1nEscjVMc6OcD1kz-O4JO2FE0

Comment: I just tried that URL `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RgKAFK5djSk&list=PLc6GzkmQ1nEscjVMc6OcD1kz-O4JO2FE0` into the top code and it seems to works fine. Are you getting an error?

Comment: Did you get an error with this code? The example URL that you hgave seemed to work ok for me. Does it fail for you? Is there another example URL that doesn't work?